# Remove application from launcher programmatically in Android

Tags: java, android, android-manifest

Is there a way of removing an activity from the home launcher at runtime? I mean removing `Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER` from its properties or something similar.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can disable a component via `PackageManager#setComponentEnabledSetting()`, which will have the effect of removing it from the Launcher.

Comment: How would this work if you later would re-install your app. Is there no problem as you have disabled it?

Comment: I tried it and it works, but I the launcher need to be restarted in order for the icon to disappear. Do you know how to refresh the launcher icons?

Comment: @yuku AFAIK, there's no way to refresh launcher icons. However, any launcher reload event, such as changing language settings, will do it

Answer (score 1):

Actually from Android 10+, it is quite difficult to hide the app launcher icon. I have used the code -

```
               val packageManager = packageManager

                **// disable the app launcher icon**
                val componentName = ComponentName(
                    this,
                    MainActivity::class.java
                )
                packageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting(
                    componentName,
                    PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
                    PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP
                )

               **// enable the app launcher icon**
                val componentName = ComponentName(
                    this,
                    MainActivity::class.java
                )

                packageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting(
                    componentName,
                    PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,
                    PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP
                )
```

When the disable code runs, it only makes the app launcher icon disabled, not hidden. But you cannot launch it, it opens the app info setting page when clicking the launcher icon.

Another way - This is another way to do that: make an app and run it in device owner mode. Then we will be able to hide/remove the app launcher icon.

Visit the link- https://www.sisik.eu/blog/android/dev-admin/uninstalling-and-disabling-apps