# Allow a USER to remove app icon from Launcher?

Tags: android, launcher

I'm trying to programatically allow the USER to decide when to remove my app (a theme which is called from another app) from the launcher.

Currently using a button:

```
getPackageManager().setComponentEnabledSetting(new ComponentName("com.package.name","Main"),PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,0);
```

Sorry I'm not a coder and I'm doing something wrong, the button shows but no effect even with a launcher or phone restart.

Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

OK, I actually found some other similar code which worked.

I had kept `intent.category.LAUNCHER` and `intent.action.MAIN` in *Main* and moved the intent that calls my app from a parent app into a new class (duh). 
Then I run the folowing on a button press by which the user can remove the icon from the launcher (requires launcher/phone restart):

```
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager(); ComponentName name = new ComponentName(this, Main.class);
pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(name, PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why is there even a launcher icon (necessary) in the first place? Does a theme need such an icon?

Apart from that: the same question was asked and answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/972933/remove-application-from-launcher-programatically-in-android): you have to restart the launcher itself to update the icon-list.

Comment: I've had no icon before but many users get confused that the app won't/doesn't launch and then rate the app poorly - so I want a help page with the option to remove the app at the user's discretion. 

I realise the question is answered in the topic you linked to, but I've tried that and I can't get it to work. Which si why I posted my code here asking for feedback.

Comment: Sorry, didn't see the remark after the code -.- Does the button-click-event fire and can the package-manager find the Component? (Debugging?)

Comment: Hi, yep the button fires. Not sure if the package manager finds the component.