# InVisible App From the user

Tags: android

I want a completely invisible app (stealth) which will not have any launcher icons and we can retrieve only if I dial a specific number in the dialer is it possible in android?

Comment: Yes it is possible.Try this question in stack [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5921071/how-to-create-a-stealth-like-android-app).I think this is what you want

Comment: I want to invoke an application when we dial a number

Comment: Try this https://code.google.com/p/right-number/